# Mapping constructor arguments to settings in the app.config

Tags: structuremap

With StructureMap, I know that you can wire constructor arguments to app settings when mapping in code, and you can specify constructor arguments when defining the DefaultInstance in the XML config, but is there a way to have the XML configuration look at its own app.config settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specific case was using Entity, so maybe this isn't applicable for everything, but rather than duplicating the same connection string information, you can use "Name=MyConnectionString" as a connection string and the framework will automatically pull the named connection string from the app.config/web.config.  This does what I need it to.